# Top tags requiring a tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Tag wikis are now prominently shown on hover [and when tagging a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74645/display-tag-excerpt-when-asking-a-question) -- all the more reason to at least write their excerpts down!

If you consider yourself knowledgeable about a game, please consider contributing tag wikis and excerpts. Stick close to our [format for tag excerpts & wikis](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/cleanup-2013-its-time-for-meaningful-and-consistent-tag-wikis/), and note that those with [less than 20k rep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) will need their edits to be approved before going live.

[5k Reviewers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), please make sure you reject [suggestions blatantly copy pasted from other sites](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)...

Comment: Wonderful idea!

Comment: One thing that might be helpful: A few links to what you might consider an *excellent* Tag Wiki to be emulated. Part of the reason I haven't bothered is, quite frankly, I haven't the foggiest idea of what to bother including. Bonus points for it being a *gaming* tag wiki. Lead by example and all that.

Comment: @Less I'm not sure what you mean; for the ones I did, I draw inspiration from Wikipedia and TVTropes without copying (to avoid the attribution requirement).

Comment: Should we also recommend using a second CW post here as a scratch space for lower rep users to suggest wiki contents? That way, we can get contributions for places where our moderately rep'd users don't quite know how to write it.

Comment: @Grace They're welcome to edit it right into the post, or as another answer :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Top tags without a Wiki or Excerpt

Wanna make a difference? Wanna earn some rep points? Why not propose some Tag Wikis and Excerpts? **+2 reputation** on approval. Gnarly!

The source for the following list is this [SEDE query: "Top tags without excerpts"](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/668431/top-tags-without-excerpts). (Note that the query can be up to a week out of date!) The tags are sorted by question count in descending order.

##### For each tag wiki excerpt you add (and that is *approved*): Please remove it from the list below.

See **[this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/how-should-i-write-tag-wikis)** for our preferred formats for tag wikis and excerpts, and remember, [don't plagiarise content!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

(This list only includes tags with 7 or more questions. To see a list of all tags with no tag wiki excerpts, use the [aforementioned SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/668431/top-tags-without-excerpts).)

| Tag | Question Count |
| --- | --- |
| [mortal-kombat-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-11) | 9 |
| [street-fighter-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-v) | 9 |
| [xcom-chimera-squad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcom-chimera-squad) | 9 |
| [cod-black-ops-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-black-ops-zombies) | 8 |
| [cod-world-at-war-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod-world-at-war-zombies) | 8 |
| [gems-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gems-of-war) | 8 |
| [holocure-save-the-fans](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holocure-save-the-fans) | 8 |
| [lost-ruins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-ruins) | 8 |
| [metroid-dread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metroid-dread) | 8 |
| [ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom) | 8 |
| [pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous) | 8 |
| [peglin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peglin) | 8 |
| [pokemon-stadium](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-stadium) | 8 |
| [star-wars-jedi-fallen-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order) | 8 |
| [tales-of-xillia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-of-xillia) | 8 |
| [detroit-become-human](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/detroit-become-human) | 7 |
| [genre-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-identification) | 7 |
| [guitar-hero-world-tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-hero-world-tour) | 7 |
| [lords-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lords-mobile) | 7 |
| [mega-man-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega-man-x) | 7 |
| [minecraft-worldguard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-worldguard) | 7 |
| [paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory) | 7 |
| [star-wars-squadrons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-squadrons) | 7 |
| [state-of-decay-yose](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-decay-yose) | 7 |
| [tales-of-xillia-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-of-xillia-2) | 7 |
| [the-surge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-surge) | 7 |
| [touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil) | 7 |
| [xbox-game-pass-for-pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-game-pass-for-pc) | 7 |

None of these tags catch your fancy? Check out [**Tag Wikis you might be able to provide**](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/581815/tag-wikis-i-might-be-able-to-provide) for a list of tags missing wikis that you've asked or answered in.

Comment: Note that it probably **not** a good idea to remove a tag from the list above until the edit is *approved*, and not simply waiting for review.  Should the edit be rejected, the list will need to be changed again.