# "Top tags without excerpts" query returning incorrect values, likely using it incorrectly

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

A few days ago, I noticed the "[Top tags requiring a wiki](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/top-tags-requiring-a-tag-wiki)" question. For those unfamiliar, it is an old post, directing users to update the wiki for popular tags.

In the answer, there is a useful list of the "Top 20", with a link to the query used to determine the 20 most used tags that do not have wiki excerpts.

After adding a few excerpts, and seeing they were approved, [I ran the query and updated the list](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1595/68). I since noticed another user adding back in the tags I had completed, and removing other tags, that I confirmed to have no wiki. I rolled back the edit, and left a comment explaining my actions.

I have gone back in, today, having pushed a wiki to the [mortal-kombat-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-x) tag. I click on the query, and I click "Run Query", confirming I am a human with a Capthca.

However, the query still shows tags that have wikis. In fact, the supposed "top 2" are [ff-record-keeper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-record-keeper) and [mortal-kombat-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-x). I added these both, myself. I have since been awarded reputation for the approvals, and there is no comment on either wiki to note that they are still awaiting approval.

Am I missing something that I potentially lucked out on, the first time? Or is there a different reason this query is no longer returning accurate data?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**query**](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/128381/top-tags-without-excerpts) given on the 'Top Tags without a Wiki' post can be **up to a week out of date**. The Stack Exchange Data Explorer from which the query is run [**isn't** updated in realtime](http://data.stackexchange.com/help):

[image: FAQ: How often is the SEDE updated?]

Therefore, the best day to check and update the query is on Mondays. However, if you click on the tags in the query, it will take you to the Arqade page for that tag:

[image: Clicking on tags]

[image: Mortal Kombat X's tag wiki]

Which **will** show an updated wiki in realtime. This is how I check when adding new tags to the answer.

I doubt there's any malice here, just a simple misunderstanding. I've edited in a warning to the [post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1595/28182) in question, hopefully in future, situations like this one will not crop up as often.

Comment: I'd also like to take a moment to say it's good to see users going out of their way to add/edit tag wikis and updating that post. So thanks everyone, you're the real MVPs :)

Comment: Just check on...Mondays? That's when its refreshed.

Comment: @Frank - added thanks :)