# Tag wikis for meta

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

We have a meta question [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/top-tags-requiring-a-tag-wiki) for an ongoing effort to add tag wikis and usage guidance for tags on the main site which is great and helpful. If we had usage guidance and wikis for ever tag on the main site, that would be wonderful.

However, we have a number of tags on meta with no guidance or wiki (though we probably only need user guidance on meta). I think we could benefit from adding them just for sanity and to help people who are new to meta. Some of the tags are relatively straightforward, but some could use a bit of clarification. Like what exactly is the difference between [suggested-edits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) and [editing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing). If I am asking a question about an edit I suggested should I use both or one or what?

We probably have some tags we don't really need or that could be grouped with others, and we can probably figure that out as we go along, but I think that with the smaller amount of tags on meta, we could probably get usage guidance for most, if not all, of the tags and the site will be a bit better off for it.

Comment: *"...what exactly is the difference between suggested-edits and editing. If I am asking a question about an edit I suggested should I use both or one or what?"* Realistically, the tagging situation on meta is a bit of a mess. I think it'd be worth trying to organise a bit of a cleanup before beginning to write wikis for them.

Comment: @Robotnik, not a bad idea. I hadnt thought as much about cleaning up the tags until i was mostly done writing this post. just was thinking it would be helpful to at least have usage guidance on them

Answer (score 2):

### Top tags without a Wiki or Excerpt

> Wanna make a difference? <s>Wanna earn some rep points?</s> Why not propose some Tag Wikis & Excerpts? Gnarly!
>
> For each tag wiki excerpt you add:
>
> - Please remove it from the list, and
> - Please find the next top tag without an excerpt [**using this query**](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.gaming/query/668170/top-tags-requiring-wikis-for-meta).
>
> Note that the query can be **up to a week out of date!** Check each tag before you add/remove it here!

1. [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) (76)
2. [answering](/questions/tagged/answering) (49)
3. [election](/questions/tagged/election) (37)
4. [reviewing](/questions/tagged/reviewing) (35)
5. [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) (35)
6. [flags](/questions/tagged/flags) (30)
7. [identify-this-game](/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) (30)
8. [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) (29)
9. [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) (28)
10. [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) (28)
11. [asking](/questions/tagged/asking) (27)
12. [community](/questions/tagged/community) (27)
13. [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) (25)
14. [community-event](/questions/tagged/community-event) (25)
15. [profile](/questions/tagged/profile) (24)
16. [top-7](/questions/tagged/top-7) (22)
17. [reopen](/questions/tagged/reopen) (21)
18. [tag-merging](/questions/tagged/tag-merging) (21)
19. [promotional-grant](/questions/tagged/promotional-grant) (20)
20. [spoilers](/questions/tagged/spoilers) (19)

Comment: Note: on the query i couldnt figure out how to get rid of the 7 standard tags (discussion, bug, etc) so if anyone can fix that, feel free to update the query. otherwise ignore those tags. I also just grabbed the formatting and most of the text from our other tag wiki for the main site post because the formatting seemed applicable and the info was mostly the same

Comment: You can use `[meta-tag:tagname]` in markdown so the tags link to the meta site rather than main. (You'll have to fork/modify the query to output that manually).

Comment: @Robotnik, thanks. i updated the tag markdown. and ill try and figure out the query

Comment: @Dragonrage I've updated the query with the changes.